# Handle concurrency with asynchronous calls in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, concurrency, callback

I have the following interface:

```
interface Callback {

  void onSuccess(Result result);

  void onFailure(Throwable t);
}
```

and the method:

```
void doSomething(Callback callback);
```

`doSomething` performs an asynchronous call to a server. The problem is that this method could be called from different components into the Android app at the same time. Taking that in mind, in order to implement `doSomething`, how can I be sure to return the result to the right callback?

What is happening is that the stored callbacks into `doSomething` are being replaced with the new requests and the wrong callback is getting the results of other requests.

What are the best practices to solve this?